# learning curve Sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I was trying Random Forest Algorithm on [Boston](https://www.kaggle.com/c/boston-housing) dataset to predict the house prices `medv` with the help of sklearn's [RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html).

Just to evaluate how good is the model performing I tried sklearn's [learning curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html) with below code

```
 train_sizes = [1, 25, 50, 100, 200, 390] # 390 is 80% of shape(X)

    from sklearn.model_selection import learning_curve
    def learning_curves(estimator, X, y, train_sizes, cv):
        train_sizes, train_scores, validation_scores = learning_curve(
                                                     estimator, X, y, train_sizes = train_sizes,
                                                     cv = cv, scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
        #print('Training scores:\n\n', train_scores)
        #print('\n', '-' * 70) # separator to make the output easy to read
        #print('\nValidation scores:\n\n', validation_scores)
        train_scores_mean = -train_scores.mean(axis = 1)
        print(train_scores_mean)
        validation_scores_mean = -validation_scores.mean(axis = 1)
        print(validation_scores_mean)

        plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, label = 'Training error')
        plt.plot(train_sizes, validation_scores_mean, label = 'Validation error')

        plt.ylabel('MSE', fontsize = 14)
        plt.xlabel('Training set size', fontsize = 14)
        title = 'Learning curves for a ' + str(estimator).split('(')[0] + ' model'
        plt.title(title, fontsize = 18, y = 1.03)
        plt.legend()
        plt.ylim(0,40)
```

If you notice I have passed `X, y` and not `X_train, y_train` to `learning_curve`.

I am not understanding should I pass `X, y` or only the training subset `X_train, y_train` to `learning_curve`.

**Update 1**

`Dimensions of my Train/Test split (75%:Train and 25%:Test)
        X.shape: (489, 11)
        X_train.shape: (366, 11)
        X_test.shape: (123, 11)`
I had few additional questions regarding the working of `learning_curve`

1. Does the size of test data set varies according to the size of train dataset as mentioned in list `train_sizes` or it is always fixed (which would be 25% in my case according to train/test split which is 123 samples) for example

   - When `train dataset size = 1` the will the test data size be 488 or will it be 123(the size of X_test)
   - When `train dataset size = 25` the will the test data size be 464 or will it be 123(the size of X_test)
   - When `train dataset size = 50` the will the test data size be 439 or will it be 123(the size of X_test)

**Update 2**

In the [blog](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/learning-curves-machine-learning/) the dataset has 9568 observations and the blogger passes entire dataset `X` to `learning_curve`.

`train_sizes = [1, 100, 500, 2000, 5000, 7654]`

In first iteration when `train_size` is 1 then the `test_size` should be `9567` but why he say that

> But when tested on the validation set (which has 1914 instances), the MSE rockets up to roughly 423.4.

Shouldnt the `test_size` be 9567 instead of 1914 for first iteration

In second iteration when the `train_size` is 100 then the `test_size` should be `9468`

What I meant to say is the `test_size` will be variable according to `train_size` correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You might be interested in chapter 2.5.4 of my Master's thesis: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.09725

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**After Update1/2**]

A learning curve shows how error changes as the training set size increases. One basically change the size of training data points and measure a desired score and compare it against a fixed *`test set`* to see how it generalizes. For you the utmost important part to note is the **fixed** *`test set`*. If you were to change the *`test set`*, that you could theoretically, how could you evaluate the performance of the same model by changing the size of the training size (because you are changing both datasets at the same time)?!

That is why you pass the the whole *`X,y`* in The Sklearn's [learning curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html), and it returns the tuple containing *`train_sizes`, `train_scores`, `test_scores`*. As far as I understood, it does a nested validation cross-validation. It basically takes the whole *`X,y`*, and split into train/test  (keeping the test data strictly independent and fix in size), depending on how you pass the *`cv`* parameter, and keep increasing the training size and record the performance scores for plotting the learning curve. This ensures a proper measure of the *optimal* model's performance.

**Concerning your Update 1**: Having just discussed the details, then your *Update 1* example scenario would be wrong. We train a model (no matter how), and would like to evaluate its performance on a *hold-out* dataset. If you change your *hold-out* dataset, you wouldn't know whether changing the training size led to the change in test score or the variability of the *hold-out* dataset itself!

**Concerning your Update 2**: This is exactly what we have been discussing so far. No matter what `train_size` is, the `test_size` would remain `1914`, as long as the same `cv` method is used.

**Example:** To further clarify let's imagine we have the following scenario:

```
train_sizes = [1, 50, 100, 200, 400, 600]
# X.shape: (1000, 5)
# len(train_sizes)=6
```

If we were to use the following settings in *learning_curve* class in sklearn:

```
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
```

The *learning_curve* returns the *`train_sizes`, `train_scores`, `test_scores`*  for six points as we have 6 train_sizes. And for these points the `train_sizes` and `test_size` would look like this:

- Point 1: train_size: 1,   test_size:200
- Point 2: train_size: 50,  test_size:200
- Point 3: train_size: 100, test_size:200
- Point 4: train_size: 200, test_size:200
- Point 5: train_size: 400, test_size:200
- Point 6: train_size: 600, test_size:200

I think `train_sizes` are clear (taken from the list we provided). The `test_size` remains fixed, and it is decided because we chose *`test_size=0.2`* in the `cv` (recall that we have had 1000 data points, so 20% of it would be -> 1000 * 0.2 = 200), and it has nothing to do with our train_sizes!! This is the *hold-out* set that we keep fixed during this experiment. Hope this last example clarifies it altogether. ;-)

I would still keep that [blogpost](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/learning-curves-machine-learning/) here as reference for others.

Comment: Thanks for the blog. I had already read about it while exploring `learning_curve`. From the blog it was not clear that _in general_ we should pass X_train or X. In the blog I guess entire X is passed.

Comment: My concern was one of the aim of `learning_curve` is to decide what our train size should be. But if we already are passing entire dataset instead of X_train then we wont have any data to increase the size of X_train( if required)

Comment: Can you please look into the updates of the question and try to answer. These were the basic doubts I had at first place when I read that blog. Please try to answer them

Comment: I understand the confusion. Let me try to update my answer that may address your concerns.

Comment: Thanks for the effort you have took in explaining my doubts. So the `test_size` always will be `Size(X) - max(train_sizes)` which in the article is `9568 - 7654 = 1914` and in my case would be `489 - 390 = 99` no matter what the `train_size` is ?

Comment: No. That is wrong. It is based on your split size in cv. Let me update my answer to elaborate on this too.

Comment: In your case you have mentioned `test_size=0.2` but in my case I have passed `cv = 10` in function argument.As per [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html) it uses [kfold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) cross validation. So my dataset of 489 will be divided in to 10 folds of 48.9 ~ 49. One of which will be a will be a test dataset. In short my `test_size` will be 49 and train size will be varying according to `train_sizes`

Comment: In the blog he use `cv = 5` that implies total of `9568` observations will be divided into 5 folds. Each fold having `1913.6 ~ 1914` observations. So the test dataset size is `1914`. Is the understanding correct ?

Comment: I know now I am expecting toooooo much from you !!!. Thank you for your patience to help someone though !!!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. Yes the last three comments are correct and your understadning is now correct. You finally digested the idea of learning curve. :-D

Comment: All because of your effort :D

Comment: Although the size of the test set is fixed, it is not guaranteed that the same indices are used in each evaluation.